# Hide article titles on Tagged Items

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, tags

I have the article Show Title set to hidden at the global article options. However, when the articles display on menu link (tagged items) the article titles are shown. Please advise, thank you.

Comment: What are you menu item settings?

Comment: Hi, everything is set on "use Global". Show Title is set to hidden at the global article options. However, article titles are shown and I can't find an option such as "show/hide article title" on tagged items menu item... There is only the "show/hide tag title".

Answer (score 1):

There are a few layers of turning the title name off.

1. If it is a category blog/list that setting will apply to the article.
2. The Article options globally will be applied next(up right corner when first going to main article page)
3. Then the article itself has the option to hide the title as well.

It is done in that order.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting to hide item title on Tagged Items view. You have to create a template override of /components/com_tags/views/tag/tmpl/default_items.php (or list_items.php, depending on which layout you use) and edit it to remove the title. Look for lines containing `$item->core_title`.